# How to call ajax on onchange dropdown by angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ajax

**My question is** 
By deafult I am getting result for 1st hotel, how to get results on onchange of hotels dropdown by using angularjs directives ?

**My Code**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='HttpController'>
   {{detail.name}} <br/>
   {{detail.address}} <br/>
   {{detail.country}}<br/>
</div>

<script>
    var hotelid=$('select#hotel_property option:selected').val();

        var data = {};
        data.Hotelid = hotelid;
        data.Action = "hotel_property";

        var helloApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

        helloApp.controller("HttpController", function($scope, $http) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    datatype:"json",
                    header: {
                        "contentType": 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    url: '/ajax',
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.detail = data.hotel_details;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "failure");
                });
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<select id="hotel_property">
 <option value="111">Taj hotel</option>
 <option value="222">oberoi</option>
 <option value="333">JW marriot</option>
 <option value="444">Grand Maratha</option>
</select>
```

By deafult I am getting result for 1st hotel, how to get results on onchange of hotels dropdown by using angularjs directives ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do something on these lines.

1. Use `ng-options` to populate hotel list
2. Use `ng-model` to bind the selected value to some variable
3. Use `ng-change` to trigger a function to handle the change.

> ```
>    <select id="hotel_property" ng-model="selectedHotel" 
>         ng-change="fetchInfo(selectedHotel)" 
>         ng-options="hotel.name for hotel in hotels">
>        <option value="">-- please select -- </option>
>    </select>
> ```

and your controller might look like this.

1. Defile $scope.hotels with array of hotel id and name.
2. define a function to fetch hotel information.

> ```
>  helloApp.controller("HttpController", function($scope, $http) {
>   $scope.hotels = [{
>     id: 111, 
>     name:'Taj hotel'
>   },{
>     id: 222, 
>     name:'oberoi'
>   },{
>     id: 333, 
>     name:'JW marriot'
>   },{
>     id: 444, 
>     name:'Grand Maratha'
>   }];
>   $scope.fetchHotelInfo(hotel){
>
>     var data = {};
>     data.Hotelid = hotel.id;
>     data.Action = "hotel_property";
>
>
>     $http({
>       method: 'POST',
>       datatype:"json",
>       header: {
>         "contentType": 'application/json'
>       },
>       data: JSON.stringify(data),
>       url: '/ajax',
>     }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>       $scope.detail = data.hotel_details;
>     }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>       alert( "failure");
>     });
>
>   }
> });
> ```

(Copy pasting code might not work)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model directive to store the selected value in the scope and use ng-change to fire the ajax query with the model value as parameter.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select